# Can the expectation value behave like a function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum

If $\langle\hat x\rangle_{\Psi} = 0$ can we conclude by the [Ehrenfest theorem](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node189.html) that $\langle\hat p\rangle_{\Psi}=0$ ?

I've seen that in [this video](https://youtu.be/q5O4FpIw9Lw?t=170) but I'd rather think that an expectation value is like a function (it's derivative can be non-zero when the function itself is zero). What do you think?

Comment: Have you understood [Schroedinger's wavepacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state#The_wavefunction_of_a_coherent_state) ?

Comment: I have studied the harmonic oscillator but not Schrödinger wavepackets, is it compulsory for my question?

Comment: It is, ***absolutely***, if you were interested in the general answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a harmonic oscillator with mass $m$ and frequency $\omega$,
and the state :
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle + i|1\rangle\right)$$
In this state we have :
\begin{align}
\langle\hat x\rangle_\psi &= \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\langle\psi|a+a^\dagger|\psi\rangle\\
&= \frac 12 \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}} (\langle 0 |-i\langle1|)(a+a^\dagger)(|0\rangle + i|1\rangle) \\
&= \frac 12 \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}} (\langle 0 |-i\langle1|)(i|0\rangle + |1\rangle + i\sqrt 2|2\rangle)\\
&=\frac 12 \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(i-i)\\
&= 0
\end{align}

and :
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle + i|1\rangle\right)$$
In this state we have :
\begin{align}
\langle\hat p\rangle_\psi &=-i \sqrt{\frac{\hbar m\omega}{2}}\langle\psi|a-a^\dagger|\psi\rangle\\
&= \frac 1{2i} \sqrt{\frac{\hbar m\omega}{2}}(\langle 0 |-i\langle1|)(a-a^\dagger)(|0\rangle + i|1\rangle) \\
&= \frac 1{2i} \sqrt{\frac{\hbar m\omega}{2}}(\langle 0 |-i\langle1|)(i|0\rangle - |1\rangle -i\sqrt 2|2\rangle)\\
&=\frac 1{2i}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar m\omega}{2}}(i+i)\\
&\neq 0
\end{align}